# Two Lead Page layouts showing different values

Tags: workflow, action

I am trying to setup a checkbox called Trial Account on my main lead page layout called Lead layout. So when a sales agent check that box and saves it a new page layout should be shown with 2 more fields. That page layout is called Trial layout.

I am trying to work this out with actions and workflow rules but I don't see if this is possible to do. 
Can you please help me out to find a way. I know this is possible with Accounts and i even tried it but when it comes to leads the page layout in actions for leads is not available.

Going more into details:

Two page layouts are created.

- Lead Layout Trial Account
- Trial Account

Now when I try to create a Record Type, it asks me to create a Lead Process.
Now when i go to lead process i create one and this is what I get. Values that i don't need.

Thanks,

Darko

Comment: Pagelayout assignments can be done with the combination of RecordTypes and profiles. We cannot change the page layouts using actions or WF.  Can you please elaborate on what you have done on Accounts?

Comment: @theGreatDanton on Accounts I have exactly created Record types and assigned the page layouts to them and it works perfectly. Now when i want to do the same with leads it says upon creation on record type that i need a process. And in the process i have values that i really don't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take following steps:

1. Create 2 Lead processes (you should use only the relevant `Status` values)
2. Create 2 record types for Lead and link them to the 2 processes
3. Create 2 page layouts for Lead
4. Assign those page layouts to the resp. record types
5. Create a workflow rule based on your checkbox being checked, and have it fire a field update that updates the record type

Comment: Thanks @Robin for the fast reply but this is what i get when it comes to leads and record types for leads.

A leads record type must be associated with a leads process. You currently do not have any active leads processes. You must create a leads process before creating the leads record type.

Comment: Right, forgot about that one. I've edited my answer to incorporate the lead processes.

Comment: When I've defined it right it was working flawless ! Thanks @Robin